# Are there any micro-controllers produced by companies based in the UK?

Tags: microcontroller

The closest I've got is a company called FTDI which produces USB ASICs.

Are there any micro controllers manufactured by or built for uk-based companies? If they do indeed exist, can you tell me how they compare with their better known counterparts? (PICs for example)

Comment: What is your point?

Comment: @abdullahkahraman Thank you for your reply. I'm asking for information regarding uC that are produced by companies based in the UK.

Comment: I think abdullah wants to know why you want to know. Is this patriotism? Do you expect UK manufactured devices to be higher quality? What's the reason behind the question?

Comment: @stevenvh I'm curious. Most phones and mobile computers are powered by ARM, which is UK-based. However, ARM only licenses its designs and doesn't implement them. Searching for UK companies that produce uCs did not yield any results, which struck me as odd given ARMs position. This got me curious about the state of uC production in the UK.

Comment: I can't think of any.  However, microcontroller companies tend to be large entities, so can have plants worldwide.  Mircochip, for example, is a US company but does their final packaging in Thailand.  Some companies use Ireland to manufacture for the EU because they used to have good tax breaks.  I don't know of any plants in the UK.  It is generally regarded as a expensive place to manufacture, but I haven't looked into the cost issues personally.

Comment: If FTDI meets your criteria, a number of their parts _are_ microcontrollers (most obviously, the embedded USB hosts); just not necessarily user-reprogrammable ones.

Comment: The planning and environmental issues around silicon fabs mean that you don't get any chips actually manufactured in the UK. But Cambridge is full of small IC companies that use TSMC for manufacture in Taiwan.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any Micro-controller manufacturer specifically in the UK, but under the broader umbrella of integrated circuit manufacturers, there are a small handfull. 'Silicon-fen' in Scotland (think the scottish version of silicon valley) or the Cambridge and Bristol areas are where most of them are based.

I'm personally aware of e2v in based in Essex, who manufacture high reliability semiconductors/electronics for space and defense applications.

Answer (score 2):

XMOS is one such company:

http://www.xmos.com/

The chips are actually made by TSMC in Taiwan.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_semiconductor_fabrication_plants), NXP (headquarters in the Netherlands) has a fab in Manchester. Though NXP has a wide range of products and I'm not sure exactly which products are manufactured in Manchester.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of this list when I posted my question. I should have search Wikipedia more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

You had mentioned FTDI in your question. They have a programmable 16-bit MCU called the Vinculum-II. This device is quite powerful and even has the specialization to be a USB host controller. There is a rich array of on board hardware peripherals on the part including USB, UART, FIFO, SPI, PWM, DMA, and TIMERS. [This is the link to the FTDI page for the part.](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/VNC2.htm)

Comment: Thank you Michael! I had no idea that the Vinculum II could be used as a general uC! It's a shame I can't up-vote answers yet.